# How do I restrict the Solr search to get only the latest matching record less than a particular date?

Tags: java, solr

H,Essentially In an EMPLOYEE Table that can have multiple records for an employee with different ENTRY_DATE I want to restrict the results of below query by 1 for each employee

SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMP_NAME IN (...) AND ENTRY_DATE < TODAY ORDER BY ENTRY_DATE DESC

Currently I am fetching all the matching results from the repo and finding the latest record in my Java code, But that creates a problem when emp_list is large and total results are greater than the MaxSize of results, In that case few employees are skipped.

Is there a way to query directly the latest record from the repo in Solr search?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have the `ENTRY_DATE` available in Solr, couldn't you sort by it there as well (if there's only one employee)? If there are multiple employees, you can use the [collapse and expand support ](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/collapse-and-expand-results.html) with the `max` parameter set (and collapse on employee name).

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh for the pointers. I was able to solve the issue using result grouping feature of Solr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Solr query gives the required result

```
q=EMP_NAME&group=true&group.field=EMP_NAME&group.limit=1&sort=ENTRY_DATE desc
```

Also you can search multiple EMP_NAME

```
q="EMP_NAME1" OR "EMP_NAME2"&group=true&group.field=EMP_NAME&group.limit=1&sort=ENTRY_DATE desc
```

Result Grouping -> https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/result-grouping.html